# ruby output from file.

Tags: ruby, file-io

I want to output data(integers) onto a file called stdout.txt.
The trouble seems to be that my code overwrites the existing data in the file
instead of adding to it line by line.

```
if failPlaces.empty? == false
  puts "position: #{failPlaces.last}"
  output = File.open( "stdout","w" )
  output << "#{failPlaces.last}\n"
  output.close
else
  puts "He Passes it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
  output = File.open( "stdout","w" )
  output << "Pass\n"
  output.close
end
```

I would like to understand why my code is behaving like this and what the solution would be.

Comment: By the way, you can simplify the file output by passing a block to `File.open`: `File.open( "stdout","w" ) { |output| output << "#{failPlaces.last}\n" }`.  Your file will be opened and closed for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks Keith, That makes it look better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a file named **stdout.txt** you can write it as such (remember to use `a` rather than `w`). `w` will overwrite everything in the file whereas `a` will append if file exists, otherwise creates a new file.

Here is a list of [Ruby IO modes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-c-new)

```
failPlaces = [1, 2]

if failPlaces.empty?
  puts "He Passes it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
  output = File.open('stdout.txt', 'a')
  output << "Pass\n"
  output.close
else
  puts "position: #{failPlaces.last}"
  output = File.open('stdout.txt', 'a')
  output << "#{failPlaces.last}\n"
  output.close
end
```

Comment: Thank you, I was using w(overwriting) whereas I should be using a(appending). Big help! thanks!